# How to prevent the position of the player to go outside screen bounds with pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to grab the screen width of the x position. So, when I change the screen size I can have it where it already is configuration to the screen size and the player doesn't run off the screen. If that makes any sense.

```py
windows = pygame.display.set_mode((1200,1000))

if player_x > pygame.display.get_surface().x-15:
    player_x = pygame.display.get_surface().x-15
```

This isn't right because it crashes the game now.

Comment: I downvoted because it's [unclear what you're asking](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion) and there are [missing exceptions details](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: what is missing that you want to know

Comment: I think you should have included the exact exception details you're facing (you say "the game crashes" but that's not very helping for us reading). Also, reading the accepted answer, I understand there was maybe missing tags like `pygame` that would have helped put more implicit context where very little explicit context was given.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll start taking notes for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make Player disappear and appear in Pacman-Style**

```py
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

x=gameDisplay.get_width()
y=gameDisplay.get_height()

if player.left > x-15:
    player.left = 0
```

Maybe not the explicit solution, but you should be able to build from it, exactly what you want ;)

Comment: Thanks it worked nicely. can you help me improve the question for next time so i can understand what i left out.

Comment: Well I have to mention that I just saw the edited version of the question. Therefore the point of your question was already pretty clear to me, but that simply might be because I encountered similar problems in the early days of my developer story :) I'd bet that Corentin will give you more details, and you can read your question's review to get more information about as well.